# Calculating every cartesian point in a circle

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, geometry

I have an array: int[][] lawn = new int[980][1280];

wich stores the values of the height of the blades in the lawn.

In my simulation i have a robot that goes around the lawn and cuts the blades.

my robot has the form of a circle with a diameter (rDiameter). 
The coordinate system is done with Double and my lawn is in Integer.

I have developped two "algorithms" that allows the robot to cut the lawn but i'm not satisfied because the precisions of my algorithms is not high enough and the performance also.

My question is, is there a way to do this other than the ideas that I have already thought of?

Or do I need to change the implementation of my lawn to get better results?

Feel free to ask anything if i was not clear enough.

Here is the code for my two algorithms (k stands for the robot), centerPosition returns the center of my robot(so the center of the circle)

```
approach with square
    int bottomLeftCornerX = (int) (k.getCenterPosition().getX() - simulParams.getKDiameter() / 2);
    int bottomLeftCornerY = (int) (k.getCenterPosition().getY() - simulParams.getKDiameter() / 2);

    for (int i = bottomLeftCornerX; i < bottomLeftCornerX + simulParams.getKDiameter(); i++) {
        for (int j = bottomLeftCornerY; j < bottomLeftCornerY + simulParams.getKDiameter(); j++) {
            ((LawnArea) lawn.getBladeHeight()).cutBladeInArea(j, i);
        }
    }
```

And here the one with the circle approach (basically it's the circonference formule present in wikipedia...):

```
for (int r = 0; r < simulParams.getKDiameter() / 2; r++) {

        for (double t = 0; t < 2 * Math.PI; t = t + 0.1) {
            Point2D p = circumference(k.getCenterPosition().getX(), k.getCenterPosition().getY(), t, r);
            int intX = (int) Math.ceil(p.getX());
            int intY = (int) Math.ceil(p.getY());
                ((LawnArea) lawn.getBladeHeight()).cutBladeInArea(intY, intX);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use the midpoint circle algorithm, but store the coordinates in an array, and then fill the circle line by line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For readability:
`k.x` is the x coordinate,
`k.y` is the y coordinate,
`k.r` is the radius.

```
for(int y = (int)Math.max(0, Math.ceil(k.y - k.r)); y <= (int)Math.min(980, Math.floor(k.y + k.r)); y++) {
    doulbe dx = Math.sqrt(k.r * k.r - Math.abs(y-k.y) * Math.abs(y-k.y));
    for(int x = Math.max(0, (int)Math.ceil(k.x - dx)); x <= (int)Math.min(1280, Math.floor(k.x + dx)); x++) {
        cut(x,y);
    }
}
```

There are two loops:
The first one is for the y-coordinate and starts at `k.y - k.r` and goes until `k.y + k.r` if the circle is completly on the field (I didn't know if it always was, if yes then you can't reach the corners), so from the top to the bottom of your screen.
The second one is for the x coordinate. The smalles and biggest x are calculated with the help of the formular (k.x - x)² + (k.y - y)² = k.r².
With that you only get points in your circle. It's a little smaller because of `double` to `int` conversion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried your code and it works wery well, but I didn't get what are you saing with the fact that I can't reach the corners.

Comment: If I would like to cut the blades in the points that I get rounding the double to a higher value is it possible with your formula?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. I was just not sure if your robot is always completely on the lawn of if it can leave it.

Comment: About the rounding up: Short answer: no. Long answer: you need to calculate sqrt(k.r² - (y-k.y)²). If you round to bigger values, then (y - k.y) may be bigger then k.r, thus k.r² will be smaller then (y-k.y)² so you end up with the square root of something negative. A way around this may be to change `Math.ceil(k.y - k.r)` to `Math.ceil(k.y - k.r - 1)`, `Math.floor(k.y + k.r)` to `Math.floor(k.y + k.r + 1)` and to add one to dx. I guess it should be the same as rounding up.

Comment: Thankyou...I have a question, can you please explain to me what your variable dx is for? I have understood that it comes from x=sqrt(r^2 - y^2) that is the circle formula, but I don't understand why is it utilized in the second loop

Comment: Maybe it's easier to understand if you draw a cicle. Then draw a straight line up- or downwards with a length <= r. It's ending point is P(k.x | y) Now draw a horizontal line which goes trough P. This line has exactly two intersections with the circle, one at (k.x - dx | y) and one at (k.x + dx | y). Those are the beginning and the end of the second for loop.

Comment: Hey, thank you I have understood the code. Unfortunately I have to change approach, I have thought of a new method that serves better my purpose, which is: I have the start position and the end position (after it’s movement) of my robot, and I want to cut all the blades from the starting position to the end position, maybe you can help me here, I’ve started with creating a Line from the start to end point but how can I cut all the "cells” touched by  the diameter of my robot?

Answer (score 1):

The first approach (based on a bounding box) is a good start.  But you now just need to add a conditional that checks whether each point inside the bounding box is also in the circle.

Something like:

```
for each (point p inside bounding-box) {
    if (p inside circle centred at k) {
        cutBlade(p);
    }
}
```

You can improve this by noticing that in each row (or column) of the bounding box, the set of blades that need to be cut are all neighbours.  If you calculate the end-points of this range, then you don't need any conditionals.

Something like:

```
for each (x inside bounding-box) {
    calculate y_first;
    calculate y_last;
    for (y = y_first; y < y_last; y++) {
        cutBlade(x,y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your fast reply, I will try the two things you suggested, in the meantime if you have others ideas let me know!