# Calculating every cartesian point in a moving cicrle

Tags: java, algorithm, multidimensional-array, geometry

I have an array: int[][] lawn = new int[980][1280];
wich stores the values of the height of blades in the virtual “lawn”.

In my simulation i have a robot that goes around the lawn and cuts the blades.

My robot has the form of a circle with a diameter (rDiameter). The coordinate system is done with Double and my lawn is in Integer.

I have to develop an algorithm that puts to 0 all the cells touched by the robot when it moves around.

I have the start and end point of the movement, which are stored in a Line2D.Double form and I want to set on 0 all the cells touched by robot (image).
Any ideas?

(Here my previous question on the same argument [every cartesian point in a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863310/calculating-every-cartesian-point-in-a-circle)

Comment: You're describing a brush algorithm.

Comment: Just apply the answer from the previous question to find all the points on your circle, then set them to 0 or whatever you wish to do. Or do you want someone else to do ALL the code for you! c'mon dude ;]

Comment: Nope...it won't work, with the circle you get tiny spots between the two circles that are not covered...

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem in 3 parts.  Part 1 is to set to 0 all points in a semi-circle.  Part 2 is to set to 0 all points in a rectangle.  Part 3 is to break the path into two semi-circles (at the ends) and a rectangle (joining them).

Note that the semi-circles and the rectangles have, in general, lines that are not axis aligned.  There are plenty of references out there on rasterizing polygons and circles.  You could look up Jack Bresenham's algorithms.  Or you could flip open any classic computer graphics text.

Comment: Thank you, I like your idea, thought about it myself but didn't know there where algorithms for that. Jack Bresenham algorithm seems fine, will try it!

Comment: Note that he did algorithms both for circles and lines.